# So I tried to make a recursive function but it results in infinite loop

Tags: python-3.x, dictionary, recursion, list-comprehension, user-defined-functions

I was attempting a coding challenge [Link](https://www.hackerrank.com/contests/coding-practice-test-9-tpc-rait-2022/challenges/find-the-winner-2-1-1)

For people who doesn't have an account here's the copied one:
Peter and Henry are playing a game on a string s of length n consisting of the characters '0' and '1'. Both players take alternate turns but Peter plays the first turn.

In every turn, the player can perform one of the following operations on the string:

Select any i, where s[i]= '0' and change s[i] to '1' and pay 1 Rupee. The other operation is to reverse the whole string and pay 0 Rupee. This operation is only allowed if the string is currently not a palindrome, and the last operation performed was not reverse. If Peter reverses the string, then Henry can't reverse the string in the next turn, and vice versa.

Reversing a string means reordering its letters from last to first. For example, "01001" will become "10010" after the reversal.

The game comes to an end when every character of string becomes '1'. The player who spends minimum rupees till this point wins the game and it is a draw if both spend equal rupees. If both players play optimally, determine whose's the winner or if it is a draw.

Input Format

The first line contains a single integer t . Then t test cases follow.

The first line of each test case contains a single integer n .

The second line of each test case contains the string s of length n, consisting of the characters '0' and '1'. It is guaranteed that the string s contains at least one '0'.

Output Format

For each test case print a single word in a new line:

"PETER", if Peter will win the game, "HENRY", if Henry will win the game, "DRAW", if the game ends in a draw.

Sample Input 0

2
3
110
2
00

Sample Output 0

PETER
HENRY

Explanation 0

In the first test case of example, in the 1st move, Peter will use the 2-nd operation to reverse the string, since doing the 1st operation will result in his loss anyway. This also forces Henry to use the 1st operation. In the 2nd move, Henry has to perform the 1st operation, since the 2-nd operation cannot be performed twice in a row. All characters of the string are '1', game over. Peter spends 0 Rupee while Henry spends 1 Rupee. Hence, Peter wins.

**This is the code and I am new to recursive functions and this code is resulting in max recursion limit.Any help would be greatly appreciated.**

```
def Winner(c,counter):
    if sum(c) == b:
        if len(set(counter.values)) == 1:
            print("DRAW")
            return
        else:
            d=index(min(counter.values()))
            print(counter.keys(d))
            return
    if c == c[::-1]:
        for i in c:
            if i==0:
                c[i] =1
            break
        counter["PETER"] +=1
        c=c[::-1]
        print(c)
        Winner(c,counter)
    else:
        c= c[::-1]
        for i in c:
            if i==0:
                c[i]=1
            break
        counter["HENRY"] +=1
        Winner(c,counter)
a=int(input())
p,h=0,0
counter={"PETER":0,"HENRY":0}
global b
for i in range(a):
    b=int(input())
    c=list(map(int,input().strip().split()))
    Winner(c,counter)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I spent several days trying to understand your code and it's logic but I was hampered by the fact that it wouldn't run and also the logic as it was layed out seemed flawed.  As a result I took it upon myself to analyze the game problem and build my own solution.  To that end and to clearly state what I considered to be the rules of the game, I have restated the rules as succinctly and clearly as possible:

#### The Game

Peter and Henry are playing a game on a string s of length n consisting of the characters '0' and '1'. Both players take alternate turns but Peter always plays the first turn.

#### The play

In every turn, the player can perform one of the following operations on the string:

1. Select any i, where s[i]= '0' and change s[i] to '1' and pay 1 Rupee.
2. Reverse the whole string and pay 0 Rupee. This option is not allowed if:

   - the previous player reveresed the string
   - the string is a palindrome

#### Ending the Game

The game comes to an end when every character of string becomes '1'.
The player who spends the minimum wins.  It is a draw if both spend equally.

#### The Problem

If both players play optimally, determine who would win or if the game results in a draw.

#### The Analysis

Assuming the above accurately describes the game play:
The first issue that needs to be addressed for any solution is to determine the meaning of ***'Optimal Play.'***   By initial observation we can deduce that for any player optimal play must comply with:

1. select string reverse if possible - this forces the opponent to make a digit selection at a penalty
2. If reverse is not an option, select a digit to reverse that results in a palindrome.  This requires opponent to also switch a digit so penalties are equal
3. If can't create palindrome, select an index and change the value at a penalty of 1

However after further evaluation this is not necessarily the correct priority, taking for example the following:

**Start: 10100**,
player 0 plays 00101 score(0,0)
player 1 plays 10101 score(0,1)
player 0 plays 11101 score(1,1)
player 1 plays 10111 score(1,1)
player 0 plays 11111 score(2,1)
**Player 1 Wins**

Alternatively
player 0 plays 10101 score(1,0)
player 1 plays 11101 score(1,1)
player 0 plays 10111 score(1,1)
player 1 plays 11111 score(1,1)
**Player 0 Wins**

As illustrated above, Player 0 can improve on the outcome by creating a palindrome on the first move rather than reversing the string.  Thus, the definition of ***optimal*** is dependent on the final outcome of the game, rather than simply selecting the best play out of the options available at any given stage of play.

An approach to implementing this logic requires that all game states be determined first and then at each turn the best end-game solution path for the player be taken.

The first step then requires we create a connected graph (GameTree) of all game states.  To keep track of the game status at each step of the game I created a GameState Class.  An instance of this class will be used to define each node of the GameTree.  Each instance of GameState will define:

- score on input [player 1, player2]
- the player to move at this state
- string on input
- prior move was reverse flag True/False
- the prior game state
- the child game states
- the end_point score of each child

So using the above example, the resulting simplified tree would conform to the following where each node is described by (Player, String_state, score, children):

```
GS0=[0: '10100', (0,0), [GS1, ..]]  
    GS1 = [1: '00101', (0,0), [GS3, ..]]  
         GS3 = [0, '10101', (0,1), [GS4, ..]]  
               GS4 = [1: '11101', (1,1). [GS5]]  
                     GS5 = [0: '10111', (1,1), [GS6, ..]]  
                           GS6 = [1: '11111', (2,1), []]  
               
         
    GS2 = [1: '10101', (1,0), [GS7, ..]]  
          GS7 = [0: '11101', (1,1), [GS8, ..]] 
                GS8 = [1: '10111', (1,1), [GS9]]  
                     GS9 = [0: '11111', (1,2), []]
```

Once the GameTree graph is defined, it is then possible to employ a Depth First Search (DFS) algorithim to travel down each branch of the tree until a leaf node is found (i.e. a node with no children), and pass back to the previous node the leaf node score.  At each node where multiple options are available, tghe function will select the best solution for the player and pass that solution up to the previous node, this continues back until all paths are searched and the best end-game move for the first player can be determined.  The following code implements this approach.

```
# Utility functions to assist in implementing optimal play
def is_palindrome(z):
    # Returns True if s is a palindrome
    return z == z[::-1]

def find_palindrome(s):
    """ Returns a list of indexes that if switched 
    will result in a palindrome position"""
    rslt = []
    k = ''
    for i, d in enumerate(s):
        k += d
        if d == '0':
            j = k[:i] + '1' + s[i+1:]
            if is_palindrome(j):
                rslt.append(i)
    return rslt    

    
def get_bestScore(l, plr):
    """ Return best score for existing move options"""
    best = None
    scr = None
    for sc in l:
        rslt = sc[(plr+1)%2] - sc[plr]
        if best == None:
           best = rslt
           scr = sc 
        else:
            if rslt > best:
                best = rslt
                scr = sc
    return scr

def find_BestMove(node):
    # Recursive function to search for leaf nodes and bactrack to define best play option
    ptr = 0
    if node.children:
        while len(node._end_options) < len(node.children):
            node._end_options.append(find_BestMove(node.children[ptr]))
            ptr += 1
        return get_bestScore(node._end_options, node.player)                        
    else:
        return node.score   

#Class to maintain game tree node states
class GameState:

    def __init__(self, parent, str_in, rvflg, score):
        self._prior = parent
        self._str = str_in
        self._player = 0
        self._score = score
        self._rvflg = rvflg
        self._children = []
        self._end_options = []
        
        if self._prior:
            self._player = (self._prior.player + 1)%2
        self._children.extend(self.get_move_options())
        
    def __gt__(self, other):
        return self.score[self.player] < other.score[other.player]
    
    def __repr__(self):
        return f"GS{self._id:02} - [{self.player}: {self.state_string} => {self.score}"
    
    def get_move_options(self):
        ''' return a list of next game states for each possible move 
        from current postion.  The list is sorted so that the best moves are
        at the begining of the list'''   
        mv_opts = []
        if not self.rvflg and not is_palindrome(self._str):
            mv_opts.append(GameState(self, self._str[::-1], True, self.score))
        sc = self._score.copy()
        sc[self._player] += 1
        popts = find_palindrome(self._str)
        for i, d in enumerate(self._str):
            if d == '0' and i not in popts:
                popts.append(i)
        for m in popts:
            nw_str = self._str[:m]+'1'+self._str[m+1:]
            mv_opts.append(GameState(self, nw_str,  False, sc))  
        return mv_opts
    
    
    @property
    def state_string(self):
        return self._str
    
    @property
    def rvflg(self):
        return self._rvflg
    
    @property
    def score(self):
        return self._score
    
    @property
    def player(self):
        return self._player
    
    @property
    def  children(self):
        return self._children

def playGame(instr):
    # Function to play the Game by building the Gamestate tree and playing optimum moves
    players = ["Peter", 'Henry']          
    cgs = GameState(None,instr, False, [0,0])
    rslt = find_BestMove(cgs)
    out_str = ''
    if rslt[0] == rslt[1]:
        out_str = 'Draw'
    elif rslt[0] < rslt[1]:
        out_str = players[0]
    else:
        out_str = players[1]
    return out_str
```

As an example of using the above code:

```
test_cases = [('00', 'Henry'), ('100', "Draw"), ('10100', 'Peter'), ('0010', 'Peter')]
for tc in test_cases:
    print(f"For Input String '{tc[0]}', Expected {tc[1]} and got: {playGame(tc[0])}")
```

Produces the following output:

```
For Input String '00', Expected Henry and got: Henry
For Input String '100', Expected Draw and got: Draw
For Input String '10100', Expected Peter and got: Peter
For Input String '0010', Expected Peter and got: Peter
​
```

Comment: Thank you, it took me days to understand this code because I am a novice in DSA but now I have understood it.Thank you so much

Comment: Your welcome, the suggested code isn't very efficient and takes way too long to run for inputs of more than 10 characters, so there are improvements that can be made.